# pusher gives no call back

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I am trying to test a basic pusher trigger event that gives me a simple alert and a console log, but it wont work. The response is received from the pusher console debug but there are no alerts. I am using laravel 5.3 and its routes and a view for this. Below is my code. I have censored the sensitive information.

route file web.php

```
Route::get('/bridge', function() {

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $options = array(
        'cluster' => 'ap1',
        'encrypted' => true
    );
    $pusher = new Pusher(
        'key censored',
        'secret censored',
        'app id censore',
        $options
    );

    $data['message'] = 'hello world';
    $pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', $data);

    return view('pusher');
});
```

and view pusher.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Pusher Test</title>
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('e5bbf707214a6223d044', {
            cluster: 'ap1',
            encrypted: true
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
        channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
           alert(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

chrome console gives me the following logs.

```
Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting
Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-ap1.pusher.com:443/app/censored key?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.2.2&flash=false"}
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 5034.8700909
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"test_channel"}}
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"test_channel"}
Pusher : No callbacks on test_channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

Comment: But while you have this app running with the console open....in another tab you log to the pusher site an create a new notification, then on the other tab it should be reflected on the console.log...did you do that test?

Comment: i did. two tabs and reload on one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You created a binding for the `my_event` event. This error is complaining that you don't have a callback for the `pusher:subscription_succeeded` event. If you want to catch that and handle it, you need to create a binding.

https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels#pusher-subscription-succeeded

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    alert('successfully subscribed!');
});
```

Comment: do i replace this channel.bind with mine with my_event?

Comment: You can bind to more than one event. That error says you don't have a handler bound to the `pusher:subscription_succeeded` event.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    // alert('successfully subscribed!');
 });

 channel.bind("App\\Events\\NewMessage", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

Comment: This is a good laravel solution. I tried to copy the laravel echo syntax of "just-the-event-name" but it wasn't working. putting the full path of the event as mentioned in this answer is definitely the solution that solved my problem: App\\Events\\EventName